# Filter on mongoDb an array of strings

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

im building a chatbot and i want to filter a MongoDb database with the input of the users

```
words=["hello","price","bye"]
```

and my db is like that [image: db]

```
{
  "Lang": "en",
  "kw1": [
    "price"
  ],
  "Keyword Group 2": [
    "test"
  ],
  "Keyword Group 3": [
    "res"
  ],
  "Type": "Text",
  "Text": "aaaaaAAAAAaaa",
  "createdAt": 1662724328993,
  "etag": "d-Zwyn11c6q6DfK+AV6RVxl9i7OJQ",
  "_version": 2,
  "updatedAt": 1662724336488
}
```

i've tried to do it like this

```
this.fetchDataFromDataSource({ channel: this.channel, collectionName: "62a985781cd96396e4e1cba3_test", filter:{ kw1: words

 } }).then((result) => {
   
   console.log(result)

         
  })
```

when the input is only a word it works well but when i send more than one word it doesn't behave as expected, how im supposed to do it?

Comment: what are you expecting vs. what are you currently getting?

Comment: Expecting the 3 entries of the db and getting an Unexpected identifier error

Comment: There is a typo in `console.log(resul)`.

Comment: fixed but it wasn't the error

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `$in` operator:

```
this.fetchDataFromDataSource({
  channel: this.channel,
  collectionName: '62a985781cd96396e4e1cba3_test',
  filter: { kw1: { $in: words } },
}).then((result) => {
  console.log(result);
});
```